# array to string conversion error on view ci

Tags: php

i have an array which is in the following format

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 [path] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Pistachios [path] => E_906.JPG ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 [path] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Almonds [path] => almond.jpg ) ) ) )
```

now what i need is i need the id ,name and path values from this array it basically has two indexes 0 and 1  i am using foreach loop for this purpose

here's my code

```
<?php 
foreach ($child3 as $key => $value){
echo $key;
}
?>
```

when is echoing out the key it prints correct 0,1 but when i try to echo the value like

```
<?php 
foreach ($child3 as $key => $value){
echo $value;
}
?>
```

it is giving me an error of **Array to string conversion** any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: because you have an array of arrays

Comment: "*...any recommendations?"* ... yes, don't try an echo an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($child3 as $key => $value){
    $id = $value['id'];
    $name = $value['path'][0]['name'];
    $path = $value['path'][0]['path'];
}
```

**this is assuming that your `[path]` always contains just one array element.

Comment: just one more thing for conceptual purpose, can you explain to me how you made that array logically like the index 0 inside the array how are they working i want to research more on advanced arrays bu i just need an initial concept

Answer (score 1):

In your second foreach loop, `$value` is the Array with key `path`. [`echo()`](http://php.net/echo) expects a string as parameter, but because `$value` is an Array, PHP tries to convert it to a string and fails.

Try [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) instead:

```
<?php 
foreach ($child3 as $key => $value){
    var_dump($value);
}
?>
```

Your Structure is this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (     <<- you tried to echo this array
        [id] => 13 
        [path] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => Pistachios 
                [path] => E_906.JPG 
            )
        )
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 14 
        [path] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => Almonds 
                [path] => almond.jpg 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

If you know this structure is fixed, try this:

```
$files = array();
foreach ($child3 as $child) {
    $files[$child['path'][0]['name']] = $child['path'][0]['path'];
}
```

So `var_dump($files)` would give you this:

```
Array (
    'Pistachios' => 'E_906.JPG'
    'Almonds' => 'almond.jpg'
)
```

Comment: my bad echoing an array but var_dump still returns an array whereas i need id,name and path values only

Comment: @uneebmeer If you are sure the structure of the Array will stay like this, you can use my edited code answer to get an Array where the key is the name and the value is the file (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<?php 
foreach ($child3 as $key => $value){
 print_r($value);
}
?>
```

Because you have $value as an array, that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: my bad echoing an array but print_r still returns an array whereas i need id,name and path values only